# Client - Agent Information Reporting Error: "DEVICE_GROUP_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: mongodb, fiware

It appears that IoT-Agent isn't receiving measures, Agent's log says device group not found [MONGO-ALARM]. Does anyone understand what this error means or how to fix it?
Agent's log:

```
time=2018-12-10T16:48:24.824Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=LWM2MLib.COAPRouter | msg=Handling request with method [POST] on url [/rd/1] with messageId [24748]
time=2018-12-10T16:48:24.826Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=LWM2MLib.UpdateRegistration | msg=Handling update registration request
time=2018-12-10T16:48:24.826Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=LWM2MLib.COAPUtils | msg=Extracting query parameters from request
time=2018-12-10T16:48:24.827Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=LWM2MLib.UpdateRegistration | msg=Updating device register with lifetime [undefined] and address [193.136.33.222].
{"op":"IOTAgent.LWM2MHandlers","time":"2018-12-10T16:48:24.827Z","lvl":"DEBUG","msg":"Handling update registration of the device"}
time=2018-12-10T16:48:24.829Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=54b6621d-65fd-43db-ac9b-fade34e4d947 | trans=54b6621d-65fd-43db-ac9b-fade34e4d947 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBGroupRegister | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Looking for group params ["resource","apikey"] with queryObj {} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2018-12-10T16:48:24.835Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=54b6621d-65fd-43db-ac9b-fade34e4d947 | trans=54b6621d-65fd-43db-ac9b-fade34e4d947 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBGroupRegister | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Device group for fields [["resource","apikey"]] not found: [{}] | comp=IoTAgent
**time=2018-12-10T16:48:24.836Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=54b6621d-65fd-43db-ac9b-fade34e4d947 | trans=54b6621d-65fd-43db-ac9b-fade34e4d947 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.Alarms | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Raising [MONGO-ALARM]: {"name":"DEVICE_GROUP_NOT_FOUND","message":"Couldn\t find device group","code":404} | comp=IoTAgent**
time=2018-12-10T16:48:24.836Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=54b6621d-65fd-43db-ac9b-fade34e4d947 | trans=54b6621d-65fd-43db-ac9b-fade34e4d947 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBDeviceRegister | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Looking for device with id [raspiSensorTV]. | comp=IoTAgent
time=2018-12-10T16:48:24.843Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=54b6621d-65fd-43db-ac9b-fade34e4d947 | trans=54b6621d-65fd-43db-ac9b-fade34e4d947 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.Alarms | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Releasing [MONGO-ALARM] | comp=IoTAgent
{"op":"IOTAgent.LWM2MHandlers","time":"2018-12-10T16:48:24.843Z","lvl":"DEBUG","msg":"Preregistered device found."}
time=2018-12-10T16:48:24.844Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=LWM2MLib.UpdateRegistration | msg=Update registration request ended successfully
{"time":"2018-12-10T16:48:24.894Z","lvl":"DEBUG","msg":"Observers created successfully."}
```

The log above appears everytime the device signals to have sent a measure, but my query for provisioned devices returns empty list:

```
curl -X GET \
  'http://localhost:4041/iot/devices' \
  -H 'fiware-service: smartGondor' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /gardens'

{"count":0,"devices":[]}
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Any one with idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Your request is showing that no devices have been successfully provisioned yet.

It is likely that you have either not provisioned a service group for your IoT Agent or not provisioned the device itself. If a measurement is received before a service group has been provisioned then the IoT Agent will not know how devices identify themselves or where to persist the measurements.

You can provision a service group in multiple ways, but one method would be as follows:

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://iot-agent:4041/iot/services' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: <xxxxxxx>' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: <yyyyy>' \
  -d '{
 "services": [
   {
     "apikey":      "<api-key>",
     "cbroker":     "http://orion:1026",
     "entity_type": "Thing",
     ...etc
   }
 ]
}'
```

Thereafter any unknown device responding with the correct `<api-key>` will create an entity called `Thing`.

Of course if you want to be more specific you can provision the device as shown:

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://iot-agent:4041/iot/devices' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: <xxxxxxx>' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: <yyyyy>' \
  -d '{
 "devices": [
   {
     "device_id":   "motion001",
     "entity_name": "urn:ngsd-ld:Motion:001",
     "entity_type": "Motion",
     "attributes": [
       { "object_id": "c", "name": "count", "type": "Integer" }
     ],
   }
 ]
}
'
```

This ensures that a device identifying as `motion001` will be stored as a `Motion` entity and various mappings will take place.

Comment: Thank you Jason Fox, but the response I get creating the service group is an error message:
`$curl -iX POST \
>   'http://localhost:4041/iot/services' \
>   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
>   -H 'fiware-service: smartGondor' \
>   -H 'fiware-servicepath: /gardens' \
>   -d '{
>     "services": [{
>         "apikey": "4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov",
>         "cbroker": "http://orion:1026",
>         "entity_type": "Device"
>
>     }]
> }'`

Comment: Rensponse:

`HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Powered-By: Express
Fiware-Correlator: 86369e48-7d69-4f8b-bdb0-23791af70f46
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 93
ETag: W/"5d-hk+jPkRqdSLah4wC5ppU2NSaRWc"
Date: Thu, 20 Dec 2018 21:56:37 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{"name":"WRONG_SYNTAX","message":"Wrong syntax in request: Errors found validating request."}`

Comment: If you are getting an error on service group creation, then obviously no service group has been created, thereafter the measurements can't be passed to the context broker.  Can you paste your command and result into the question to provide more (erm... **context** )

Comment: OK so the syntax is incorrect - check that the JSON is valid and that the attributes match the requirements for your agent - some of the attributes will differ - `resource` for example is used with HTTP but not MQTT.

Comment: You don't state which IoT Agent you are using, but I'm guessing LWM2M - there is a confguration example in the [documentation](https://fiware-iotagent-lwm2m.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deviceProvisioning/index.html)

Comment: Your initial question was asking what causes a `DEVICE_GROUP_NOT_FOUND` error, which is common to all agents. To fix it for a specific device is a separate question, and it would be useful to know what you have tried.  Could you  follow the instructions in the configuration example in the LWM2M documentation and paste your results for each step there - the provisioning method described in my answer may not be relevant to your specific agent.

Comment: Okey, about apikey please, I don't know the device api before-hand. Should I provide and arbitrary code to use as apikey during group provision?